# How to integrate oauth with gwt?

Tags: facebook, gwt, oauth-2.0

Here is my code, how do I use oauth to get the data such as user_id or first and last name of the user and sign them to fields? Should I implement them in the onSuccess method?

```
  private void addFacebookAuth(){

      loginButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            final AuthRequest req = new AuthRequest(FACEBOOK_AUTH_URL, FACEBOOK_APP_ID).withScopes(
                    FACEBOOK_EMAIL_SCOPE, 
                    FACEBOOK_BIRTHDAY_SCOPE, 
                    FACEBOOK_USERID_SCOPE,
                    FACEBOOK_USER_LAST_NAME_SCOPE,
                    FACEBOOK_USER_FIRST_NAME_SCOPE).withScopeDelimiter(",");

            AUTH.login(req, new Callback<String, Throwable>(){

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable reason) {
                    Window.alert("Error:\n" + reason.getMessage());

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String token) {
                //  Window.alert("Got an OAuth token:\n" + token + "\n"
                  //          + "Token expires in " + AUTH.expiresIn(req) + " ms\n");
                RootPanel.get().remove(loginButton);


                }
            });


            }
        });
        RootPanel.get().add(loginButton);  

      }
```